# jQuery get value from hidden input in column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got the following HTML table...

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nr.</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Info</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Laura</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" value="1"><a href="#" class="info">Info</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Sabrina</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" value="2"><a href="#" class="info">Info</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I get with jQuery the value of the hidden input field, when the link is clicked?

```
$(".info").click(function() {
  // Here I need to find out the value...
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5DEa9/

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you do it :

```
$(".info").click(function(e) {
  //just in case, will be useful if your href is anything other than #
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).prev('input[type="hidden"]').val());
});
```

`prev` method will search for the previous element, which is where your `input[hidden]` is.

And its `href`, not `hre`, in the `<a/>` tags.

Comment: Don't forget to `return false;` or `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Hmm..just added that..didnt bother because the `href` was pointing to `#`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: An `href` of `#` doesn't magically stop the default action.  `#` is used to jump around to different anchors in the page.  `#` will jump to the top of the page and add `#` to the URL, unless you stop the default action.

Comment: @hungerpain: Read my previous comment.  `#` doesn't magically stop the default action.

Comment: @RocketHazmat i didnt mean to say it would stop the #. I felt like (in most cases) the # in the url is negligible.

Comment: @Rocket, you're right, I would have sworn I read somewhere that "go to top of page" behavior was a thing of the past. I stand corrected.

Comment: @hungerpain: It will also jump to the top of the page.

Comment: oh yeah.. i faced that problem sometime back. didnt quite recollect. Thanks for the eye opener @RocketHazmat

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I only knew that because I recently forgot about this and wondered why my page kept jumping to the top.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use attributes `<a href="#" data-hidden="1" class="info">` don't need use hidden fields

```
$(".info").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).data('hidden')); // or $(this).attr('data-hidden');
});
```